# using command subsitition in a bash for loop

Tags: bash, command-substitution, programming

I am probably making an obvious mistake but I could use a strong hint:-)

```
for file in *; do ls $file | var=$(ls $file | grep -Eo '.{18}$' | cut -d '.' -f1 |sed 's/.\{12\}/&./'); echo "var is $var. File is $file";done
```

**RESULT**: $var is empty. $file is not. **Why is $var empty?**

When I manually put my test string in $file and run as follows, $var contains what I want:

```
var=$(ls $file | grep -Eo '.{18}$' | cut -d '.' -f1 |sed 's/.\{12\}/&./')
```

So there is something about the for loop which is causing this. It seems the $var variable has a scope limitation preventing me from using in following statements.

Have a great Easter:-)

**full example:**

As asked, here is an example to hopefully clarify my query.
The file's `inventory_a_test-20190605161153.txt1` date must match the date in its file name. First, I set the file to the wrong date:

```
$ touch inventory_a_test-20190605161153.txt
$ ls -l --full-time inventory_a_test-20190605161153.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 0 **2021-04-05** 15:02:05.000000000 +0200 inventory_a_test-20190605161153.txt
```

Now I want to write a command flow like the one below as a for loop in bash to correct the date:

```
$ file=inventory_a_test-20190605161153.txt
$ ls $file | grep -Eo '.{18}$' | cut -d '.' -f1 |sed 's/.\{12\}/&./'
201906051611.53
$ touch -a -m -t 201906051611.53 $file
$ ls -l --full-time inventory_a_test-20190605161153.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 0 **2019-06-05** 16:11:53.000000000 +0200   inventory_a_test-20190605161153.txt
```

Comment: The limitation is that each command in a Bash pipeline runs in its own subshell scope. The value of var is locally defined only between `var=` and the matching `;`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by the pipeline `ls $file | var=(...)` in the loop? It looks as if the command substitution is not reading the output of that `ls` command.

Comment: $file contains a file name. In the file name is a time stamp which needs some formatting.  After the grep and sed commands, $var contains, for instance, 201906051611.53. I then want to use $var with touch to alter the file timestamp

Comment: @Jeroen1000 please [edit] your question and add some example file names and the output you expect from them. This isn't a very safe approach.

Comment: @Jeroen1000 thanks for the edit, that is helpful. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part doesn't make sense:

```
ls $file | $(something)
```

The `$(command)` format means "run `command` and treat its output as a variable". This isn't something that can accept piped input. I think what you *meant* to write was:

```
for file in *; do 
    var=$(ls "$file" | grep -Eo '.{18}$' | cut -d '.' -f1 |sed 's/.\{12\}/&./'); 
    echo "var is $var. File is $file"
done
```

However, this will fail quite badly for strange file names. [You really don't want to be parsing the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). More importantly, the `ls` is absolutely not needed here! You already *have* the file name so the `ls` is adding nothing but a complication and possible source of error. This should do what you want:

```
for file in *; do
    timestamp=$(sed -E 's/.*(.{12})(..)\.[^.]*$/\1.\2/' <<<"$file")
    touch -a -m -t "$timestamp" -- "$file"
done
```

The `sed` will print only the last 14 characters of the file that come before the final extension (`\.[^.]*$/` will match a `.` and then 0 or more non-`.` until the end of the file name), but separates the last 2 from the previous 12 with a `.` effectively generating your timestamp.

Comment: No, thank you for that kind solution. I understand the regex but your sofistication is well beyond what I could have come up with:)

Comment: @Jeroen1000 you can simplify that to `timestamp=$(grep -Eo '.{18}$' | cut -d '.' -f1 |sed 's/.\{12\}/&./' <<<"file")` to use the exact same approach you had, but this time it will work and won't depend on `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

@terdon no thank you for your kind solution. For the other linux beginners out there.  I had some time zone issue as well so the final result is:

```
for file in *; do
     timestamp=$(sed -E 's/.*(.{12})(..)\.[^.]*$/\1.\2/') <<<"$file"
     TZ=UTC-2 touch -a -m -t "$timestamp" -- "$file"
done
```

ps: I use this site to analyse a regex: https://regex101.com/

Comment: If you think that terdon's answer was the most helpful one, then you may [accept that answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Also note that the site that you link to does not support POSIX Basic Regular Expressions (BREs), but a few other dialects of regular expressions used in specific languages, none of which is a Unix shell.  This means that expressions that the site says does the right thing may not work as expected (or at all) with standard Unix tools like `sed`.